# Installing Kubuntu from Ubuntu DVD?

Tags: kubuntu

I want to install Kubuntu 13.10, but I just have Ubuntu 13.10 CD. Can I install Kubuntu with some method? I know about install kubuntu-desktop after installation, but should be another way...

Comment: customize the ubuntu 13.10 live cd.

Comment: What do you mean "another way"? Installing `kubuntu-desktop` after installing Ubuntu *is* the way.

Comment: you don't know another way...

Answer (score 0):

Download Kubuntu CD/DVD. The difference between installing Ubuntu with `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop` and installing Kubuntu CD/DVD is that the CD/DVD has the packages of `kubuntu-desktop` and doesn't have to download them.

The last chance you have is download all the .deb packages of `kubuntu-desktop` and install them manually over Ubuntu (instead of apt-get which uses Internet connection).